# $L^p$ as quotient space: Book recommendation

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

For my thesis, I need to define $L^p$ spaces but in the literature (Real and Complex Analysis by Rudin, Measure Theory and Integration by  de Barra, ...) it is not defined as a set of equivalence classes by a quotient space construction. Do you know any literature where this is done explicitly?

Comment: I'm not sure what emphasis is being placed here on "a set of equivalence classes by a quotient space construction".  The notion of two functions being equivalent by agreeing everywhere except on a set of measure zero is explicit in Rudin's *Real and Complex Variables*.  Perhaps you have a notion of representing this equivalence by a "quotient space" construction, but I don't know that anyone thinks working directly with operations well-defined with respect to the equivalence classes is logically deficient.

Comment: @hardmath I mean something like the construction in equation (4.8) on page 116 of the lecture notes https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/measure.pdf. I did not want to cite lecture notes, thats why I was asking here.

Comment: Note that the line above (4.7) says simply:  $$f\sim^\mu g \iff f=g \;\;\; \mu-\text{almost everywhere}$$ So the quotient space construction in those lecture notes simply invokes the equivalence relation (and follows it with a note about the norm mapping being well-defined on these and the convenience of omitting the explicit mentions of equivalence classes.

Comment: Many authors make the same construction and use the same notation ($L^p$ versus $\mathcal L^p$) to distinguish between the set of functions versus the quotient space. Cohn's [Measure Theory](https://www.amazon.com/Measure-Theory-Birkhäuser-Advanced-Lehrbücher/dp/1461469554) comes to mind as a book which treats this carefully (and is a very good book in general).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hardmath has pointed out, Rudin's treatment is surely adequate. But to your question: just glancing at some of the books I have on my desk at the moment, I see that Royden's *Real Analysis* and Bogachev's *Measure Theory* would make good recommendations.

Answer (score 4):

The approach taken by Rudin in *Real and Complex Variables* (2nd edition, at hand) is to introduce the equivalence relation "a.e. [$\mu$]" on measurable functions in Chapter 1 (page 28), Section "The Role Played by Sets of Measure Zero". He notes, for example, that transitivity of this relation "is a consequence of the fact that the union of two sets of measure $0$ has measure $0$."

He then develops a bit of the machinery that is needed later, including the notion of $\mu$-*completion* of a $\sigma$-algebra (Thm. 1.36) and the notion of *convergence* of a function sequence "almost everywhere".

It may appear from the opening passages of Chapter 3 (page 66), Section "The $L^p$-spaces", that he is about to omit any formal definition in terms of equivalence classes, e.g. when expressing the $p$-norm:

$$ ||f||_p = \left\{\int_X |f|^p d\mu \right\}^{1/p} $$

The previous (Chapter 1) discussion already details that the integral being well-defined on the "a.e. [$\mu$]" equivalence classes.

This apparent omission is merely a pedagogical pause.  Explicit discussion then takes place on pages 68-69 of the importance of these equivalence classes to the definition of a *metric* $d(f,g)$ on this function space by taking "the distance between $f$ and $g$ to be $||f-g||_p$."  Thus:

> The only other property which $d$ should have to define a metric space is that $d(f,g) = 0$ should imply that $f=g$.  In our present situation this need not be so; we have $d(f,g) = 0$ *precisely when* $f(x) = g(x)$ *for almost all* $x$.

More paragraphs explain about the equivalence classes forming a metric space with respect to the $p$-norm:

> When $L^p(\mu)$ is regarded as a metric space, then the space which is really under consideration is therefore *not a space whose elements are functions, but a space whose elements are equivalence classes of functions.*  For the sake of simplicity of language, it is, however, customary to relegate this distinction to the status of a tacit understanding and to continue to speak of $L^p(\mu)$ as a space of functions.  We shall follow this custom.

There follows the book's first really important result (Thm. 3.11) about the $L^p(\mu)$ spaces, that these are a *complete* metric space, i.e. that every Cauchy sequence converges.

Comment: Indeed. I had only considered page 66 on its own because I was looking for a very short definition for the appendix for my thesis in statistics (for functional pca, you need L^2 Hilbert spaces). Thanks for the additional context you gave (+1).